# angular js state provider with dot in url not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router

I am using angular js state provider. I want my url like this. 
http://localhost:8080/state1/state1.html . It says "Cannot GET /state1/state1.html".
Here is the code

```
$stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
        url: '/state1/state1.html',
        templateUrl: "partials/state1.html",
        controller: 'MyCtrl'
    });
```

It works fine when i remove .html . How to handle **dot** in this scenario. I am using node server

Thank you

Comment: If you have a 404, it means that you are talking about the `.html` in `templateUrl: "partials/state1.html"`. The problem is coming from your server and not from angular.

Comment: Please read my updated question, it is problem with url only. when i remove .html in url (/state1/state1), it works fine

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand why you add the .html at the end of the url.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with node server's or front-end router config, which most happened under webpack-dev-server, or say it express's imperfection. And accoring to [RFC3986](http://ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), 

`unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"`

you cannot convert `.` into `%2e` unless you package it as your customed solution.

If your router is implemented front-end with history API, you can package your angular app and serve then compiled under Nginx or Caddy server, and It would work normally.

For node server or others, you'd better specify the `*.*` in the router config.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

    routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        
        $stateProvider

            .state('main', {
                url: '/',
                template: '...'
            })
        
            .state('home', {
                url: '/urlto/home.html',
                template: 'Home page'
            })
            
            .state('about', {
                url: '/urlto/about.html',
                template: 'about page'
            });
            
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

    <div ng-app="routerApp">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="#">AngularUI Router</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">

        <div ui-view></div>

    </div>
    </div>
```

Seems to work fine for me. Maybe you have problem with HTML5 mode and server app routing?

Answer (score 0):

URLs with dots work just fine. [Here in this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MytV66SmZs1eT7n5dPNH?p=preview), the state `withdot` has the url `/withdot.html` configured and I added url parameters with dots just for good measure. 
There is no specific handling of the dots (`.`) in the url specs, as opposed as dots in the state names that mean parent/child relationship.